# How to prove that a first-countable topological space satisfies "closed-compact" if and only if it is compact Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

A topological space is called $C$-$C$ iff the closed sets in $X$ coincide with the compact sets in $X$.

> **Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space which satisfies the first axiom of countability. Then $(X,\tau)$ is $C$-$C$ iff $(X,\tau)$ is compact and Hausdorff.**

**Proof**: Necessity: It suffices to show that $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff. Let $ x\ne y$ and suppose that $x$ and $y$ cannot be separated by open sets. Let $\{ U_{i} \}$ and $\{V_{i} \}$ be monotone decreasing open bases at $x$ and $y$, respectively. Since $C$-$C$ implies $T_{1}$, we may assume that $x\notin V_{i}$ for all $i$ and that $y\notin U_{i}$ for all $i$. Take $ x_{i} \in U_{i} \cap V_{i} $ for each positive integer $i$. So  $x = \lim x_{i} $. Let $ F = \{ x \} \cup \{ x_{i}:i= 1,2,...\}$; $F$ is compact and thus closed by condition $C$-$C$, but $y \notin F$ and $ y = \lim x_{i} $. This is a contradiction.

> (a) What does it mean "monotone decreasing open bases"?
>
> (b) Why  "$x = \lim x_{i}" $?
>
> (c) Why " $y \not\in F$ and $ y = \lim x_{i} $ "?

Comment: Each point has a countable local base $(U_i)_{i\ge1}$. If we take $V_1=U_1$ and $V_n=U_1\cap...\cap U_n$, then we get a local base such that $V_{n+1}\subseteq V_n$

Comment: This appears to be a perfectly acceptable set of questions a-c.  I think some may have downvoted for readability.  I've put an edit in the queue.

Comment: Question (b) and (c) are highly trivial. Please take a careful look at the definitions of the $U_i,\ V_i$ and $x_i$, and the definition of convergence.